# Webkit weird 1px underline on text

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

At http://www.wsl-ltd.co.uk/ i have a 'special offer' badge positioned absolutely with some text floated and relative inside.

For some reason, Webkit browsers are applying a red underline to some of the text - I have tried everything but just can't for the life of me work it out.

Does anyone know if this is a weird quirk of webkit, or is it my CSS? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bug in WebKit.

Define `text-decoration:none;` on the `<a>` element itself - should help.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Makes sense when you think about it, as these things usually do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with styles on `<a>` element. I think you could insert following to CSS to fix it.

```
.ie6wrap a {text-decoration:none}
```

(I checked it, you use `.ie6wrap` only for one element, so it should be safe)

If you want more details, following CSS is responsible for it:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:focus{
    color: #d58d31;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

You seem to remove underline on child elements of that `<a>`, but Webkit doesn't work in such way, because underline is under `<a>`, not on child `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the spans that contain the text wrapped in a single `<a>` tag, so the text is being underlined. You'll need to override the stylings to handle this, or move the `<a>` tag someplace else.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because those spans are under

```
<a href="contact-us">
```

which has the following style:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:focus {
  color: #D58D31;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```